# echo $$(($${$(pound)v} > 64 ))

Tags: shell

I'm reading a ninja.mk script file, and there is a part as shown below:

```
my_ninja_suffix_too_long := $(filter 1, $(shell v='$(KATI_NINJA_SUFFIX)' && echo $$(($${$(pound)v} > 64))))
```

the `$(pound)v` will be expanded to `$#v` so `echo $$(($${$(pound)v} > 64 ))` will be expanded to `$((${#v} > 64))`, am I right?

If this is right, what's the meaning of `$((${#v} > 64))`?

Can you help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a makefile question, because the string you're referring to is being passed to the shell not interpreted by make.

So the question you should be asking is, what's the meaning of `$((${#v} > 64))` *to the shell*.

Well, the bash man page says:

```
${#parameter}
          Parameter length.  The length in characters of the value of
          parameter is substituted.
```

So, `${#v}` is the number of characters in the variable `v`.  The value of `$((expr))` is the result of the mathematical expression, and boolean expressions are either 0 (false) or 1 (true).